# Joining a NSArray of objects into a string, but need to be able to specify property

Tags: objective-c, arrays, string, join

I have a `NSArray` of `Foo` objects.

```
 @interface Foo : NSObject
 {
 }
 - (NSString *) name;
 @end
```

I want to be able to join all these `[Foo name]` results into one `NSString`.

In C# I would get a array of these by using LINQ, creating a Array of it, and feeding it to `String.Join()`:

```
 List<Foo> foo = [..];
 String.Join(",", foo.select(F => F.name()).ToArray());
```

Is something like this possible in Objective-C?

I know about `[NSArray componentsJoinedByString]`, but how would I just easily select the `[Foo name]` properties of all the objects without manually looping trough its contents?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
[[myArray valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@","]
```

([docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey:))

Comment: Yup -- though I believe OP wants it joined by `@","` or `@", "`.

Comment: @bbum yep, just saw and fixed

Comment: Would this technically be slower than just iterating the array and appending the comma manually? Because `valueForKey` iterates through the entire array once. And then I presume `componentsJoinedByString` will do another iteration, therefore it's done twice.